# Why doesn't the whole signal get absorbed by the termination resistor in high-speed designs?

Tags: impedance-matching, high-frequency, high-speed

We normally parallelly terminate with a matching (50 Ω) resistor in high-speed designs. Normally, the load/receiver is high impedance, but if we terminate it with a 50 Ω resistor, wouldn't the whole signal go through the termination instead of the load? I think I am missing something. Maybe the load is not supposed to absorb anything but how can it detect anything without any absorption?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The termination resistor at the end of the line does dissipate almost all the signal energy, which is why it prevents reflections. If it did not dissipate the incoming signal, that would mean it is not matched to the transmission line, and that mismatch would cause a reflection.

However, it's a resistor: when it is dissipating the whole signal power sent by the source, there's voltage across it. The voltage is not zero. So the chip input senses voltage and reads the signal. If we squint a little and imagine the termination resistor is part of the receiver (which it is) then it's as if the receiver was absorbing the whole signal power.

Inputs do not have infinite impedance, usually there is some capacitance plus bondwire inductance, so the termination is never perfect, and there is always a little bit of reflection. As long as it's small enough to maintain a healthy noise margin, there is no problem. Some chips have on-die termination resistor for better matching.

If there is no termination resistor at the receiver, most of the signal is reflected. Then it is dissipated in the termination resistor at the source (it should really be called "source matching resistor" but whatever).

When the source emits a constant logic level, source termination resistors don't dissipate any power, but termination resistors at the receiver dissipate because they see a constant voltage.

Comment: Let's say you use parallel source and termination resistors. Will that hurt the design? will it make the input impedance high?

Comment: Parallel source resistor makes no sense

Comment: @bobflux A parallel termination resistor on both ends is common in bus networks, like PCI (not PCIe, which is point-to-point) or coaxial ethernet (not modern ethernet, which is also point-to-point). In that case, there are many devices on the line, any of which can be either source or receiver, and you can't put termination resistors on all of them for obvious reasons.

Comment: Oh, ok, yes in that case it makes sense

Answer (score 3):

> *We normally parallelly terminate with a matching (50 ohms) resistor in highspeed designs.
> Normally, the load/receiver is high impedance but if we terminate it
> with a 50 ohm resistor wouldn't the whole signal go through the
> termination instead of the load?*

With data transmission on a PCB such as when storing data in high-speed memories, the termination resistor is at the source end and, it's in series with the driver output. Of course, with bi-directional data transfers, there is a series termination at both ends.

On more rugged serial links, a parallel termination resistor at the receiver is often used to prevent signal reflections (as does the series terminator).

So, in the case of a parallel termination resistor, it must be placed at the end of the line. Because it is at the end of the line (with an insignificant distance to the receiving circuitry) the voltage across the terminator is easily "read" without too much of a reflection (providing a reasonably high-impedance receive circuit is used).

Answer (score 2):

The termination is there to match the impedance of the line and prevent reflections.  It will absorb power, but not enough to load down the driver significantly.  Your load (receiver) needs very little power to detect the state of the line, and the driver can put out far more than the termination absorbs, so everything's fine.  It's kind of like wearing sunglasses--they block some light, but in cases where you'd wear them, there's still enough for you to see clearly.